# SimpleMessageListenerContainer used with taskExecutor with default auto_acknowledge

Tags: spring-jms

When added taskExecutor configuration to SimpleMessageListenerContainer  with IBM MQ JMS provider, following exception is thrown after each onMessage execution:-

```
    Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0033: A synchronous method call is not permitted when a session is being used asynchronously: 'getTransacted' The JMS specification does not permit the use of a session for synchronous methods when asynchronous message delivery is running. Create a separate session if you wish to use both synchronous methods and asynchronous delivery simultaneously.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:313)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:388)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.**JmsSessionImpl.checkSynchronousUsage**(JmsSessionImpl.java:2378)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.getTransacted(JmsSessionImpl.java:1525)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.getTransacted(MQSession.java:801)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.**AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary**(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:571)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.**AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener**(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:481)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:439)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:311)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1$1.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Looking at AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener method, after invoking the listener it commits the transacted session or acknowledges on if CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE. 
The exception is thrown as per the JMS specification - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html 
"Once a connection has been started, any session with one or more registered message listeners is dedicated to the thread of control that delivers messages to it. It is erroneous for client code to use this session or any of its constituent objects from another thread of control. The only exception to this rule is the use of the session or connection close method.

When taskExecutor with auto_acknowledge is supported by SMLC why this is happening?
We are on Java 7, Spring 3.0.5, MQ 7.0.3. Here is our configuration:-

```
    <task:annotation-driven executor="notifExecutor" />
<task:executor id="notifExecutor" pool-size="5-10"  keep-alive="60" queue-capacity="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<bean id="jmsOptInOutSMSContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqWakeUpSMSFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="optInOutSMSQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="optInOptOutSMSListener" />
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
        <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="false" />
        **<property name="taskExecutor" ref="notifExecutor" />**
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: What does your task executor look like? Are you running this in Websphere? As far as I can remember, Websphere requires you to use its thread pool and any attempt to fork a thread that he's not managing will prevent you to use managed resources (such as JMS sessions).

Comment: My application is deployed in Tomcat 7 and using MQ client jars to connect to MQ servers.

Comment: Looking at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV26277 I tried setting this JVM property at startup - -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.wmq.jmssession.asyncMethodsAllowed
=getTransacted  for first few messages this worked but later didn't and we started getting the same warning message again.